Why is .read() causing the file pointer to move to unexpected positions?
My tutor has tasked with making a program that receives user input for the first name, surname and percentage mark of a student and saves the data and the record number to a text file, each item on its own line and a specific number of characters in length. I should then use the .read() and .seek() methods to extract the data and output it. This is the code I wrote to attempt the task:
LENGTHS = {"record_no":2, "firstname":10, "surname":10, "mark":3}
RECORD_LENGTH = 33


def get_record(record_no):
    with open("students.txt", "r") as students:
        record_start = record_no*RECORD_LENGTH
        students.seek(record_start)

        record = {"record_no":None, "firstname":None,
                  "surname":None, "mark":None}
        for key, length in LENGTHS.items():
            text = students.read(length)
            record[key] = text
 
            # To skip the newline character:
            current_pos = students.tell()
            students.seek(current_pos + 2)

    return(record)


with open("students.txt", "w") as students:
    students.write("{record_no:<{length}}\n".format(
        record_no=0, length=LENGTHS["record_no"]))

    firstname = input("Enter the student's firstname\n>>> ")
    students.write("{firstname:<{length}}\n".format(
        firstname=firstname, length=LENGTHS["firstname"]))

    surname = input("Enter the student's surname\n>>> ")
    students.write("{surname:<{length}}\n".format(
        surname=surname, length=LENGTHS["surname"]))

    mark = input("Enter the student's mark\n>>> ")
    students.write("{mark:<{length}}\n".format(
        mark=mark, length=LENGTHS["mark"]))

print(get_record(0))


However, when using the above code the program did not give the desired output. For example, when inputting "Arthur" as the first name, "Dent" as the surname and "42" as the mark, I get an output:
{'record_no': '0 ', 'firstname': 'Arthur    ', 'surname': '\nent      ', 'mark': '\n2 '}

I originally had the line
students.seek(current_pos + 2)

as
students.seek(current_pos + 1)

but this left newline characters in the output:
{'record_no': '0 ', 'firstname': '\nArthur   ', 'surname': '\nDent     ', 'mark': '\n42'}

I added some print statements to the code to output the position of the file pointer after each use of .read() or .seek(), and this was the output:
Start position: 0

Length of record_no: 2
Position after record_no: 2
Position after skipping newline character: 4

Length of firstname: 10
Position after firstname: 18446744073709551631
Position after skipping newline character: 18446744073709551633

Length of surname: 10
Position after surname: 18446744073709551643
Position after skipping newline character: 18446744073709551645

Length of mark: 3
Position after mark: 18446744073709551648
Position after skipping newline character: 18446744073709551650

After reading firstname, the file pointer should be at position 14, but clearly it wasn't. Apparently, the file pointer can reach such positions if it is made to go to a position that does not exist (I'm assuming that means after the end of the file), but I made sure that the .read() method wasn't causing me to exceed the length of the file (which, when storing 1 record, is the same as RECORD_LENGTH: 33). I also used .seek() to go directly to and print the characters (and their associated Unicode values) at positions at and around where the issue occurred, but nothing seemed wrong with the outputs, except that when I printed all of the characters in the file out at once, only 29 characters were outputted, not 33. When I  was printing some of the characters at specific positions, it seemed that there were always 2 newline characters next to each other (not how it appears in the text file), but only 1 was outputted when I printed the whole file.
This is the format of the text file for reference:
0 
Arthur    
Dent      
42 

I understand that there are simple work-arounds, but I'm more concerned with what is actually happening in the code. Any answers about optimal solutions and especially explanations of the problem would be most appreciated.

Quote from docs: "In text files (those opened without a b in the mode string), only seeks relative to the beginning of the file are allowed (the exception being seeking to the very file end with seek(0, 2)) and the only valid offset values are those returned from the f.tell(), or zero. Any other offset value produces undefined behaviour". See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Windows translates \n to \r\n when writing text files and vice versa when reading. Use rb (binary) mode instead

@AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні, writing the file in binary mode sorted everything out (though reading it in binary mode wasn't necessary in this situation). Thanks.

Being line-oriented with known line lengths seems redundant. Just read entire lines, and (if you feel like it) raise an error if a line length differs from what is expected.
